# How can I make a select statement appear when another select statement is selected

Tags: php, jquery, html

So my "type1" select statement will select an issue category, and then based on that issue I want a dropdown of employees that deal with that issue in another drop down. Also how do I make all the hidden select statements occupy the same space?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IssueReport</title>
        <script src = "../../jquery.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }
            #box {
                padding: 5px;
                color:black;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #0000E6;
                border-width: 2px;
                background-color: #58C6EB;
                width: 162px;
                height: 687px;
                float: left;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            .word{
                color: #0000E6;
            }
            .buttons{
                background-color: #CCFFFF;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function showForm(){
                    var issue = document.getElementById("type1").value;
                    if(issue == 'Program Glitch'){
                        document.getElementById("IT1").style.display = "block";
                    }
                    $("#type1").onchange(function{
                    });
                }
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#sub").click(function(){
                    var user_issue = $("#issue").val();
                    var user_priority = $("#priority").val();
                    var user_type = $("#type1").val();
                    var user_author = $("#author").val();
                    $.post("BugReport.php",{issue:user_issue,priority:user_priority,type1:user_type,author:user_author},function(data){
                        $("#result").html(data);
                    });
                });
                $("#sub").click(function(){
                    document.getElementById('issue').value='';
                    $('#type1').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                    $('#priority').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">
        <h3 class = "word" style = "margin:10px 30px 30px 30px;">Issue Report</h3>
        <div class = "word" style = "width: 100px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">Type Of Issue:</div>
            <div style = " max-width: 150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 2px">
            <form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
            <select onchange = "showForm()" class = "buttons" name = "type1" id = "type1" style = 'max-width: 150px;'>
            <?php
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "user";
                    $password = "pass";
                    $database = "database";

                    $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
                        if($con->connect_error){
                        die("Connection failed " . $con->connect_error);
                    }
                $sql1 = "select issue_name, issue_description from Issue";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $issue = $row['issue_name'];
                    $des = $row['issue_description'];
                    echo "<option value = '$issue' title = '$des'>$issue</option>";
                    }
            ?>
            </select>
            </form></div>
        <form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
        <div id = "Buyers1" style = "visibility:hidden;"><select class = "buttons" name = "author" id = "Buyers" style = "margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                <?php 
                    $sql = "select first, last from Employee where department_id = '1'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $name = $row['first'] . ' ' . $row['last'];
                        echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";

                    }
                ?>
            </select></div></form>
            <div id = "Operations1" style = "visibility:hidden;"><form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
        <select class = "buttons" name = "author" id = "Operations" style = "margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                <?php 
                    $sql = "select first, last from Employee where department_id = 2";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $name = $row['first'] . ' ' . $row['last'];
                        echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";

                    }
                ?>
            </select></form></div>
            <div id = "IT1" style = "display:none;"><form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
        <select onchange = "showForm()" class = "buttons" name = "author" id = "IT" style = "margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                <?php 
                    $sql = "select first, last from Employee where department_id = 3";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $name = $row['first'] . ' ' . $row['last'];
                        echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";

                    }
                ?>
            </select></form></div>
            <div id = "CustomerService1" style = "visibility:hidden;"><form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
        <select class = "buttons" name = "author" id = "CustomerService" style = "margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                <?php 
                    $sql = "select first, last from Employee where department_id = 4";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $name = $row['first'] . ' ' . $row['last'];
                        echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";

                    }
                ?>
            </select></form></div>
            <div id = "HR1" style = "visibility:hidden;"><form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
        <select class = "buttons" name = "author" id = "HR" style = "margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                <?php 
                    $sql = "select first, last from Employee where department_id = 5";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $name = $row['first'] . ' ' . $row['last'];
                        echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";

                    }
                ?>
            </select></form></div>
            <div id = "Logistics1" style = "visibility:hidden;"><form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
        <select class = "buttons" name = "author" id = "Logistics" style = "margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                <?php 
                    $sql = "select first, last from Employee where department_id = 6";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $name = $row['first'] . ' ' . $row['last'];
                        echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";

                    }
                ?>
            </select></form></div>
        <form action="BugDisplayAndReply.html" method="post">
        <label></label><br>
        <textarea style = "max-width: 156px; background-color: #F3F9FF; border-color: #0000E6;" cols="20" rows="34" name="issue" id = "issue" placeholder = "Enter Your Issue Here" "></textarea></form><br>
            <div class = "word" style = "width: 50px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">Priority:</div>
            <div style = "width: 70px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 2px">
            <form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
            <select class = "buttons" name = "priority" id = "priority">
                <option value = "Low">Low</option>
                <option value = "Regular" selected>Regular</option>
                <option value = "High">High</option>
                <option value = "Urgent">Urgent</option>
            </select>
            </form></div>
        <div style = "width: 50px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 2px">
        <input class = "buttons" type ="submit" name = "sub" value = "Submit" id = "sub"></div>
        <div id="result"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sidenote: you can cut your code down without the CSS and other irrelevant stuff.

Comment: You're seriously not adding mysql connections in your views are you?

Comment: Depends on how much data is involved...first selection could pull from array of data in page if it's not huge to have all issues and people available...if not make an ajax call to get the data based on selection. No idea what `occupy same space` means

Comment: `<form action="xxx.html"`? have you instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP?

Comment: I think I may have left my microphone off.